# add a header file in xen and use the file in two directions

Tags: makefile, xen

I want to add a header my_header.h in xen/include/public/ and use it in xen's tool; so this my_header.h should also be linked to tools/include/xen/

However, it does NOT work. When I recompile, `Make tools` create the soft links for all of the old files (except my_header.h) under xen/include/public.

My question is:

Do I need to change anything in tools/include/Makefile?

The tools/include/Makefile is as follows:

```
XEN_ROOT = $(CURDIR)/../..
include $(XEN_ROOT)/tools/Rules.mk

.PHONY: all
all: xen-foreign xen/.dir

.PHONY: xen-foreign
xen-foreign:
    $(MAKE) -C xen-foreign

xen/.dir:
    @rm -rf xen
    mkdir -p xen/libelf
    ln -sf $(XEN_ROOT)/xen/include/public/COPYING xen
    ln -sf $(XEN_ROOT)/xen/include/public/my_header.h xen
    ln -sf $(wildcard $(XEN_ROOT)/xen/include/public/*.h) xen
    ln -sf $(addprefix $(XEN_ROOT)/xen/include/public/,arch-x86 hvm io xsm) xen
    ln -sf ../xen-sys/$(XEN_OS) xen/sys
    ln -sf $(addprefix $(XEN_ROOT)/xen/include/xen/,libelf.h elfstructs.h) xen/libelf/
    ln -s ../xen-foreign xen/foreign
    touch $@

.PHONY: install
install: all
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/arch-x86
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/arch-x86/hvm
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/foreign
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/hvm
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/io
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/sys
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/xsm
    $(INSTALL_DATA) xen/COPYING $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen
    $(INSTALL_DATA) xen/*.h $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen
    $(INSTALL_DATA) xen/arch-x86/*.h $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/arch-x86
    $(INSTALL_DATA) xen/arch-x86/hvm/*.h $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/arch-x86/hvm
    $(INSTALL_DATA) xen/foreign/*.h $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/foreign
    $(INSTALL_DATA) xen/hvm/*.h $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/hvm
    $(INSTALL_DATA) xen/io/*.h $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/io
    $(INSTALL_DATA) xen/sys/*.h $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/sys
    $(INSTALL_DATA) xen/xsm/*.h $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEDIR)/xen/xsm

.PHONY: clean 
clean:
    rm -rf xen
    $(MAKE) -C xen-foreign clean
```

In my understanding, it should create the link for my_header.h, but I don't know why it does NOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you delete the `xen/.dir` file?  That file has no prerequisites, which means that if it exists make assumes that it's up to date.  So changing the rule won't have any effect, unless you also delete that file.

Comment: Hi @MadScientist, Thank you so~ much for your help! It works now after deleting the .dir file. I have a quick question: I think xen/.dir: in the Makefile is just a label to let the make know which commands to use when do `Make XXX`. How can it be a file which does exist in the system?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.  `xen/.dir` is a make target and a target is not just a label: a target usually refers to a real file on the filesystem.  Make decides whether to run the recipe (commands) associated with the target by checking the time-last-modified of the target against any prerequisites that are defined for that target.  Since make is checking modification times, the target and any prerequisites _must_ be real files, else they would have no modification time.  You can turn targets into pure "labels" using the `.PHONY` special target.